# Regex match any word followed by a number (but the word can contain special characters like diacritics or accents)

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex function that takes a string and matches any word followed by a comma and a year.

```js
function getAuthorFromTitle(title) {
  var regexForauthor = /(?<author>\w+(?=, \d+))/gs;
  var resultRegEx = regexForauthor.exec(title);
  var author = resultRegEx !== null ? resultRegEx.groups.author : "0000000000";
  return author;
}
```

This works great for titles containing English characters, but if I have any Diacritics or Accents the script returns null.

```
console.log("This works", getAuthorFromTitle("Robert Bresson, 1951"));
console.log("This does not work", getAuthorFromTitle("Kornél Mundruczó, 2014"));
```

Any idea on how to match words that include Diacritics or Accents?

If you want to fiddle with the code please check out this Codepen: https://codepen.io/anything/pen/XWjwgea?editors=1011

Comment: `var regexForauthor = /(?<author>[\w\p{L}]+(?=, \d+))/gus;` will do.

Comment: omg, thank you @WiktorStribiżew! Works perfectly! ❤️